# How can I check if a domain/subdomain has a specific A record?

Tags: python, dns, a-records

I am wondering if I can check the existence of an DNS A Record and if it's hooked to a specific IP address.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, perhaps with an example of what you want to do?  You can just look up a hostname and see if there exists a corresponding `A` record (using, e.g., [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/)).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.dnspython.org/examples.html - that is page with examples for build in module. You can use ipython to experiment. Just do:

```
import dns.resolver
answers = dns.resolver.query('zaborowski.ifno.pl')
for rdata in answers: print rdata
```

You will get exception or ip.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted.